# Abrir ventana emergente en mi WebView

Tags: android-studio, webview-android

desde el navegador de Windows cuando entro a una página web donde después de registrarme se muestra una nueva ventana emergente, esta ventana emergente se muestra sin problemas, pero cuando intento hacer esto mismos en Android desde un WebView esa ventana emergente no aparece, después de introducir el usuario y contraseña se sigue mostrando la misma página.

Este es el código que tengo puesto en la clase que extiende de Fragment

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );   
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls( true ); 
    mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls( false );
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode( true );
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort( true );
    mWebView.setInitialScale(1);

    mWebView.loadUrl( "http://paginaweb.es" );


    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                      boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {

            WebView nuevoWebView   = new WebView(getActivity());

            nuevoWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );   
            nuevoWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
            nuevoWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom( true );
            nuevoWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls( true );   
            nuevoWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls( false );  
            nuevoWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);  

            nuevoWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode( true );
            nuevoWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort( true );
            nuevoWebView.setInitialScale(1);

            nuevoWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            view.addView(nuevoWebView);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(nuevoWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();

            nuevoWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return true;
        }

    });
```

Que puedo hacer para que esa ventana emergente se pueda ver en el WebView?

Comment: Nadie sabe una solución para poder mostrar la nueva ventana emergentes dentro del WebView ?